# LinkedIn API - How to find Mutual Connections between User 1 and User 2 at company A

Tags: javascript, json, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to create a 3rd party app that is able to list my mutual connections at a certain company.

However I can't seem to find the API on any documentation that gives me the ability to see mutual connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no option to do that using the API.
[Here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/connections-api) in the documentation, you can see it says you can only see 1st degree connections.

Comment: Acknowledging what you've said - I think there could be a way to check with a Partner Program APIs. However I am not sure what those entail and LinkedIn Support has been extremely unhelpful. 

Surely with a token after authorization I can view the connections between myself and someone else?

Comment: Nope, according to the API even with Partner Program APIs you cannot do that.
you can only view the user connections (the user's friends) and details about them